# Capturador de Input (onChange) no funciona con React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

¿Alguien me puede explicar porque la app no cambia correctamente el valor `titulo` (variable en el State) cuando el usuario usa este input `(onChange={(e) => setTitulo(e.target.value)}` ?

Parece que esa línea no esta haciendo su función correctamente.

```
const [titulo, setTitulo] = useState();


 <input
            isRequired={true}
            type="text"
            className="editor_title"
            defaultValue={titulo}
            onChange={(e) => setTitulo(e.target.value)}
```

Cuando el usuario clicka el botón para enviar el nuevo título:

```
 <button
            onClick={changeTitulo}
            className="submit_form"
            type="submit"
          >
            Guardar
          </button>
```

La app debe enviar el titulo

```
 function changeTitulo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    API.put(`articulos/modificar/${parseInt(id_articulo)}`, { id: parseInt(id_articulo), titulo: titulo }).then(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      },
      axiosConfig
    );
  };
```

Sin embargo no lo cambia. He hecho `(console.log)` en algunas partes del componente y tiene un comportamiento raro y no lo entiendo.

En otro post en StackOverflow he leído que es el event.preventDefault() el que esta produciendo este comportamiento inesperado, pero si no lo pongo, entonces la app se recarga automáticamente)

Código completo:

```js
xport default function EditArticle() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id_articulo } = useParams();

  const [article, setArticle] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => getArticle());

  const [contenido, setContenido] = useState();
  const [titulo, setTitulo] = useState();
  
  const getArticle = async () => {
    const articleResponse = await fetch(
      API... +
        parseInt(id_articulo)
    );
    const data = await articleResponse.json();
    setArticle(data);

    setTitulo(data.titulo);
    setContenido(data.contenido);
  };

  function changeTitulo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    console.log(titulo)

    API.put(`articulos/modificar/${parseInt(id_articulo)}`, { id: parseInt(id_articulo), titulo: titulo }).then(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      },
      axiosConfig
    );
  };

  function deleteArticle() {
    if (window.confirm("¿Estás seguro que quieres borrar este artículo?")) {
      API.delete(
        `articulos/eliminar/${parseInt(id_articulo)}`
      )
        .then(() => console.log("articulo eliminado"))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));

      alert("El artículo ha sido borrado. Ahora podrás crear uno nuevo");
      // Go back to Index page:
      navigate("/");
    } else {
      console.log("anulada operacion");
    }
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <form  className="markdown-editor-post">
        <label>
          <input
            isRequired={true}
            type="text"
            className="editor_title"
            defaultValue={titulo}
            onChange={(e) => setTitulo(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button
            onClick={changeTitulo}
            className="submit_form"
            type="submit"
          >
            Guardar
          </button>
        </label>
        <h3 className="author_text">Autor: {article.autor}</h3>
        <h3 className="author_text">Fecha: {article.fechaCreacion}</h3>

        <h3 className="editor_subtitle"> ¿Qué quieres editar?</h3>
        <div className="container_editor_text">
          <textarea
            isRequired={true}
            type="textarea"
            defaultValue={contenido}
            onChange={(e) => setContenido(e.target.value)}
            className="editor_textarea"
            useRef="TheContentInput"
          />

          <div className="container_mirror">
            <MarkdownPreview
              rehypePlugins={[rehypeHighlight]}
              source={contenido}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <button className="submit_form" type="submit" colorScheme="brand">
          Guardar
        </button>
      </form>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con que no la envía correctamente? Envía `undefined`? Envía el título incompleto?

Comment: Envía una string, pero la que hay en el state al principio del render. Por alguna extraña razón onChange funciona porque SI permite al usuario escribir en el input, pero a la hora de enviar "titulo", no envía lo que el usuario ha escrito. Sino lo que había antes.

Answer (score 0):

En la función esperas recibir un evento, esta parte es correcta, pero, ¿dónde tomas el título y lo aplicas?

```
function changeTitulo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Toma el título para poder usarlo
    let titulo = e.target.value;

    API.put(`articulos/modificar/${parseInt(id_articulo)}`, { id: parseInt(id_articulo), titulo: titulo }).then(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      },
      axiosConfig
    );
};
```

Sin embargo, al declarar el componente envías una cadena:

```
<input
    isRequired={true}
    type="text"
    className="editor_title"
    defaultValue={titulo}
                               // Estás enviando una cadena
    onChange={(e) => setTitulo(e.target.value)}
>
```

Solo cambia para enviar el evento:

```
onChange={(e) => setTitulo(e)}
```

Comment: No entiendo...¿porque no debería enviar una cadena? Y por qué no cojes el titulo directamente del estado? He probado tu código y Me envía una cadena vacía. (he puesto (e) => SetTitulo(e) ) porque event no me deja

Comment: @JavierCake, si envías una cadena, entonces no puedes usar `e.preventDefault()`, porque es método corresponde a eventos y no a cadenas.

Comment: @JavierCake, cierto, el parámetro debe ser solo `e`.

Comment: Entiendo. Lo he cambiado a event.preventDefault() como dices. Igualmente, me sigue sin funcionar. Me esta volviendo loco este error :S

Answer (score 0):

Proba realizando estos cambios:

**State:**

```
const [titulo, setTitulo] = useState("");
```

**Input:**

```
<input
  required
  type="text"
  className="editor_title"
  value={titulo}
  onChange={(e) => setTitulo(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar el estado del titulo en el input para poder ver el input.
Con pasar `value={titulo}` en props deberia ser suficiente. Si sigue fallando prueba quitando default value.

```
const [titulo, setTitulo] = useState();


 <input
            isRequired={true}
            type="text"
            className="editor_title"
            defaultValue={'Ejemplo'}
            value={titulo}
            onChange={(e) => setTitulo(e.target.value)}
```